# __doPostback Javascript function cause continous postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am loading textbox value from document.ready function jquery. So textboxchange event is not triggered from codebehind c#. so i use __doPostback javascript function. Now the Textbox_change event is triggered but non stop posstback occurs.

```
   <script>
    function putData() {
        document.getElementById("<%= txtEmpNo.ClientID %>").value = "xyz";
        __doPostBack('<%= txtEmpNo.ClientID %>', "txtEmpNo_TextChanged");
       };
    }
</script>
```

This is my Javascript code.

Kindly help to resolve multiple postback

Comment: You're calling `putData` from doc ready?  `__doPostBack` does essentially `$("form").submit()` - so you're submitting the page as soon as it loads and the submit reloads the page which submits on load... etc

Comment: Did you try `$("#<%= txtEmpNo.ClientID %>").change()`?

Comment: Yes I am Calling putdata in ready function

Comment: I tried $("#<%= txtEmpNo.ClientID %>") but it throws Cannot read property 'srcElement' of undefined